# can the gradient of a harmonic function =0 at some interior point of a manifolds with two ends?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, harmonic-functions

M is a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with two ends. There exists a nonconstant bounded  harmonic function f defined on the whole M. Then is it possible that $|\nabla f|=0$ at some interior point at M? Please give examples if it is possible.

Comment: Presumably you want $f$ to be nonconstant?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,u)=xy$ on open unit disk in the Euclidean plane.

One can also prove existence of such functions on each complete 2-ended Riemannian manifold which is not an annulus. However such proofs (the ones I know) will be non-constructive, they are based on Dirichlet method.

It follows from the paper

P. Li and L. Tam, Harmonic functions and the structure of complete manifolds, J. Differential Geom. 35 (1992), p. 359-383.

that given a complete Riemannian manifold $M$ with two ends $E_1, E_2$, there exists a proper harmonic function $f: M\to (0,1)$ which converges to $0$ on the end $E_1$ and to $1$ on $E_2$. If $f$ does not have critical points, then $M$ is diffeomorphic to the product $N\times (0,1)$. Thus, to construct an example, take a manifold with 2 ends which is not diffeomorphic to a product of another manifold with an interval. For instance, 2-dimensional torus with 2 disks removed will do the job.

Comment: :The function is defined on the whole manifold and bounded. Your answer is not what I want.

Comment: My whole manifold is the open disk.

Comment: Sorry,you are right. I think I should add a condition that M has two ends.

Comment: @user34233 : the same example will work for two ends if you remove a nonzero point from the open disk. I think what you really want is completeness of the metric: All my examples are incomplete.

Comment: Yes, you are right, so I add "comlete". But If I remove a nonzero point from the open disk, then it has two ends? By the way, I just typed "@studiosus:", why did it not appear?

Comment: Yes, an open disk with a point removed has two ends, if you remove two points it will have 3 ends and so on.